# Http connection freezes when request's content-length exceeds real content length

Tags: python, apache, http, sockets, tcp

I have a very basic python script that does HTTP connection.

```
import socket

def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "192.168.56.21"
    s.connect((host, 80))
    msg = """GET /lol /HTTP1.1
Content-Length: 10    

%s""" % ("*" * 9)
    s.send(msg)
    print msg
    print s.recv(1000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see, Content-Length header exceeds real content length. When I run this script, it freezes for 5 mins, and after that I got record in apache log that request took 5min to execute and got HTTP 400 response.

```
192.168.56.21 - - [01/Apr/2011:15:07:52 +0300] "GET /lol /HTTP1.1" 400 358 "-" "-" 47 531 300011809
```

I am ok with that, but what I do not understand is why apache freezes for 5 min and keeps connection open during that time.

```
apache2   3947 www-data   19u  IPv6  17165       TCP 192.168.56.21:www->192.168.56.21:53112 (ESTABLISHED)
python2.6 4636   meuser    3u  IPv4  17164       TCP 192.168.56.21:53112->192.168.56.21:www (ESTABLISHED)
```

I assume that apache waits for amount of bytes specified in Content-Length until some timeout happens and it throws 400 Bad Request.

I tried it against production sites and obviously I got response immediately.

Can someone explain what is going on here on TCP level and what I am missing apache configuration - I want to get rid of such 5 min waiting.

Comment: According to the spec, the HTTP request should be: `GET /lol /HTTP1.1\r\nContent-Length: 10\r\n\r\n*********` i.e. use `\r\n` for header field separation and double `\r\n\r\n` for header/body separation. Not sure about the size. The common sense says that the server should wait for the 10th octec to arrive and exit by timeout, which is what you are watching.

Comment: Yep, made a typo at paste code. edited question.

Comment: Tried KeepAliveTimeout, but doesn't seem to help. What apache option I need to check?

Comment: @Stipa: KeepAliveTimeout should affect that behavior. It is read-timeout for the socket, but I'm not sure about the apache option. I think, this is an expectable behavior. And why should can't send the correct `Content-length:`?

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate attack vector on my system.

Comment: From apache conf - KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the same client on the same connection. So not something that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it is Timeout directive in apache conf. 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout